# Why is System.-Encoding and the Default-Encoding different (.NET Core)?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-core, encoding

I have a C# .NET Core application. 
I run

```
System.Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.WebName);
```

and I get utf-8

However, if I open PowerShell, and issue

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default
```

I get

```
IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-1
EncodingName      : Westeuropäisch (Windows)
HeaderName        : Windows-1252
WebName           : Windows-1252
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1252
```

Why is the system-encoding different from the default-encoding ? 
And how do I get the system-encoding under these circumstances ? 
I mean, I figured out I can get Windows-Codepage 1252 in .NET Core with

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").WindowsCodePage
```

but how do I determine the system's codepage ?

Comment: What version of PowerShell did you use? Are you using the .NET Framework-based PowerShell that ships with Windows, or did you use PowerShellCore?

Comment: @Dai: The one installed by default. I can also use the Visual Studio 2019 powershell, or the ISE PowerShell (all installed), but each and every one returns windows-1252.

Comment: FWIW, on my machine (Windows 10, version 1809), I `utf-8` is displayed as the default in my .NET Framework-based PowerShell,  in.NET Framework, and in .NET Core.

Comment: Ultimately, the number of times you should ever use `Encoding.Default` is essentially zero; moving it to UTF8 was a deliberate choice in .NET Core, so that it is at least *predictably* useless

Comment: @Marc Gravel: Agree with you on that, 
but I have a bunch of SQL scripts that I need to merge, 
and there is NO BOM (sucks), and all the encodings are different. 
Some are UTF8, those that are not UTF8 are system-default, 
but different systems have different defaults, 
and files created on the prod-system to overwrite need to be read 
with the system-default, which is what notepad uses. 
Notepad should also save files in UTF8 by default, if nothing else is specified. 
That is the whole source of the problem. Notepad users...

Comment: @StefanSteiger ultimately, if you have SQL scripts - those files presumably came from "other users", who would have written them on *their* machine, not the local machine - so in many ways the local config is irrelevant (I'm starting from a premise here that most people don't do SQL development on the production servers, or deployment servers)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I'm willing to wager those files were created on the production machine with notepad, with the text copied over remote-desktop and copied into a file created with notepad, with the production system encoding. Yea, Win32_QuickFixEngineeering greets you ;)

Comment: @StefanSteiger you know you can copy/paste files in explorer with remote-desktop too, right?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: And you should know that on production systems, this is blocked for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, got it myselfs, what still works is getting the codepage over the current culture (or the InstalledUICulture):

```
public static System.Text.Encoding GetSystemEncoding()
{
    // The OEM code page for use by legacy console applications
    // int oem = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage;

    // The ANSI code page for use by legacy GUI applications
    // int ansi = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage; // Machine 
    int ansi = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage; // User 

    try
    {
        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(ansi);
        return enc;
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    { }


    try
    {

        foreach (System.Text.EncodingInfo ei in System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings())
        {
            System.Text.Encoding e = ei.GetEncoding();

            // 20'127: US-ASCII 
            if (e.WindowsCodePage == ansi && e.CodePage != 20127)
            {
                return e;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    { }

    // return System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```cs
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
var enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(0);
```

The value `0` means `CP_ACP` for the native API. This continues to work on .NET 6.

Comment: And that will also work on Linux ?

Comment: Yes, it returns UTF-8 on Linux.

Comment: What I mean is - does it return the actual system encoding ? Or just statically UTF-8 ? If it just statically returns UTF-8, then it's of no use.

Comment: I don't see that documented. According to the docs, "the default code page returned by Encoding.GetEncoding(0) is not recommended": 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=net-6.0

Comment: On Linux/macOS it returns UTF-8 statically. On Windows it returns the system ANSI encoding.

The mention in the documentation specifically says you should not use it because the ANSI code page can be different based on system settings of the machine. However, if you are dealing with external data already encoded in the ANSI encoding that's exactly what you want.